# Having 5 Fields Run off 1 Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form in access used to store/edit data. One of the functions is a search function. I type any data into its related field and hit the search button and it pulls up any record matching the description. I have 5 different combo boxes for different training courses to recommend. Right now if I wanted to look up 1 course I would have to select that course in each combo box because it could be in any of the 5. I was wondering if there was a way to rewrite it so I can put the course in just one of the 5 and it will still search all 5 fields for the data? The search query code is below:

```
SELECT CDData.EmployeeID, CDData.EmployeeName, CDData.Gender, CDData.EEOC,
CDData.ReadinessLevel, CDData.Division, CDData.Center, CDData.EmployeeFeedback,
CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee1, CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee2,
CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee3, CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee4, 
CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee5, CDData.Justification, CDData.Changed
FROM CDData
WHERE 
(((CDData.EmployeeID) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtEmpID] & "*") AND 
((CDData.EmployeeName) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtEmpName] & "*") AND 
((CDData.Gender) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboGender] & "*") AND 
((CDData.EEOC) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboEEOC] & "*") AND 
((CDData.ReadinessLevel) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboReadyLvl] & "*") AND 
((CDData.Division) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDivision] & "*") AND 
((CDData.Center) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtCenter] & "*") AND 
((CDData.EmployeeFeedback) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtFeedback] & "*") AND 
((CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee1) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1] & "*") AND 
((CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee2) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment2] & "*") AND 
((CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee3) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment3] & "*") AND 
((CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee4) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment4] & "*") AND 
((CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee5) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment5] & "*") AND 
((CDData.Justification) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtJustification] & "*") AND ((CDData.Changed) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboChanged] & "*"));
```

Comment: This should be easier with training courses stored as separate rows instead of columns.  Are you committed to keeping the current table structure?

Comment: Yes because the purpose is to recommend these specific courses. And they can recommend up to 5 or even just 1.

Comment: @HansUP do you have a different recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to normalize this data a bit.  I would have a separate table with EmployeeID and DevelopmentForEmployee in it, and link that back to your main table.  This way, you could search this new table for DevelopmentForEmployee and just INNER JOIN that query to the main table on EmployeeID for this purpose.  Then, it should end up looking something like:

```
SELECT CDData.EmployeeID, CDData.EmployeeName, CDData.Gender, CDData.EEOC,
CDData.ReadinessLevel, CDData.Division, CDData.Center, CDData.EmployeeFeedback,
CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee1, CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee2,
CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee3, CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee4, 
CDData.DevelopmentForEmployee5, CDData.Justification, CDData.Changed
FROM CDData
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM MyNewTable WHERE DevelopmentForEmployee Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDevelopment1] & "*") 
as DevForEmp 
   ON CDATA.EmployeeID = DevForEmp .EmployeeID
WHERE 
(((CDData.EmployeeID) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtEmpID] & "*") AND 
((CDData.EmployeeName) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtEmpName] & "*") AND 
((CDData.Gender) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboGender] & "*") AND 
((CDData.EEOC) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboEEOC] & "*") AND 
((CDData.ReadinessLevel) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboReadyLvl] & "*") AND 
((CDData.Division) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboDivision] & "*") AND 
((CDData.Center) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtCenter] & "*") AND 
((CDData.EmployeeFeedback) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtFeedback] & "*") AND 
((CDData.Justification) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![txtJustification] & "*") AND
((CDData.Changed) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmCDData]![cboChanged] & "*"));
```

Might need some tweaking, but that's probably pretty close.